# I want to be able to change a variable to true with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i want to make my button so it changes to true in the Script part. This is so a random number will appear in the p element

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<button>
random number
</button>
<p id="randomnumber">

</p>



</html>
<script>
if (document.getElementById('button').clicked == true)
{
document.getElementById("randomnumber").innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random()*21)+2);

}


</script>
```

Edit:I was also wondering how to assign the random number to a variable so i can use the random number as a variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: The way your code is written, your conditional statement will only be evaluated once at the time of page load. You need to change this out for an event handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: fisrt of all if you have trouble with your code you need put [code snnipet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Jeremy try this code please.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<button id="button">
random number
</button>
<p id="randomnumber">

</p>



</html>
<script>
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("randomnumber").innerHTML = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 2);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `element.addEventListener()`

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.querySelector("#random-number").textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 2);
```

```html
<button id="button">random number</button>
<p id="random-number"></p>
```

Some tips:

- use dashes in element ID's
- format your code cleanly
- use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.getEementById()`
- use `element.textContent` instead of `element.innerHTML`

Comment: Can you explain why `querySelector()` is better than `getElementById` in this case when the former is using an ID anyway? What I've read online shows no difference in this context.

Comment: They both work. But `querySelector` is more generic and therefore 1) consistent with the code base when you aren't querying by ID, and 2) less bug prone if you change the query to be non-id.